# Spark Streaming Job memory usage increasing over time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am Running a spark streaming job in yarn-cluster mode. This will fetch records from kafka Queue and then create a dataset and do some operations on the Dataset. Job run smoothly for about an hour after that there are some abnormal processing times. I have seen that memory consumed gradually increased with time. I have used the spark.cleaner.ttl to clean up the memory. But still has this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are there any Exceptions ? Specifically OutOfMemory or Memory leak.

Comment: I have run the job continuously for 2 days but didn't get any exceptions. there are spikes in processing time in every 5 minutes